# Best way to install ros simulation for turtle bot 3 with docker for debian:buster

Tags: docker, ros

What do I have to do to run the Turtlebot 3 Simulation as described in http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/ on a `debian:buster` system using docker?

The steps for `debian:stretch` using repositories in http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Debian are not working with `debian:buster`, see https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg/issues/125

Comment: I finally found an answer by myself, changed the question to fit the answer and posted the answer, hoping it is useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my question.

Create a `Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full-jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends screen

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
ros-kinetic-joy \
ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-joy \
ros-kinetic-teleop-twist-keyboard \
ros-kinetic-laser-proc \
ros-kinetic-rgbd-launch \
ros-kinetic-depthimage-to-laserscan \
ros-kinetic-rosserial-arduino \
ros-kinetic-rosserial-python \
ros-kinetic-rosserial-server \
ros-kinetic-rosserial-client \
ros-kinetic-rosserial-msgs \
ros-kinetic-amcl \
ros-kinetic-map-server \
ros-kinetic-move-base \
ros-kinetic-urdf \
ros-kinetic-xacro \
ros-kinetic-compressed-image-transport \
ros-kinetic-rqt-image-view \
ros-kinetic-gmapping \
ros-kinetic-navigation

RUN mkdir -p /root/catkin_ws/src/ \
&& cd /root/catkin_ws/src/ \
&& git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs.git \
&& git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.git \
&& git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations.git

RUN /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash; cd /root/catkin_ws && /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make && /opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/kinetic install"
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends vim bash-completion sudo

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils

RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash robo
RUN echo "robo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/robo && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/robo

COPY ./start_simu.sh /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/start_simu.sh

USER robo
WORKDIR /home/robo
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Add a file `start_simu.sh` in the same directory, containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -dmS turtlebot_fake /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash;env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger roslaunch turtlebot3_fake turtlebot3_fake.launch"

sleep 2

screen -S turtlebot_fake -X screen /bin/bash -c "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash;env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch"

source "/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash"
exec "/bin/bash"
```

Now built your docker image using `sudo docker build --tag ros:turtlebot3_fake_node .`

Run the image:

```
xhost +local:root
sudo docker run -it --env="DISPLAY" --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-uni
x:rw" ros:turtlebot3_fake_node /usr/local/bin/start_simu.sh
```

If image is stopped, do `xhost -local:root`.

The simulation is running in `screen`, connect to it via `screen -R`.